# Issue on aligning image and link in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `<img>` and `<a>` in it.
But I have problem to align them vertically middle.  I have tried to use floats, absolute positioning and other stuff but nothing has effect.

```
<div id="hoverDiv">
                <img alt="" width="32px" height="32px" src="http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211776868.png" />
                <a href="#">TestAccount </a>
                <div class="showme">
                    <ul id="menuAccountItemList">
                        <li>...
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img {
   vertical-align:middle;
}​
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zGPsC/)** (border added to show alignment).